# Offset stacked images created using ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

I am currently using the following ImageMagick command to create a "Polaroid stack" of photos from multiple JPG images.

```
convert \
    img-5.jpg -thumbnail 300x200 -bordercolor white -border 10 \
    -bordercolor grey60 -border 1 -bordercolor none \
    -background none -rotate -4 \
    \
    \( img-2.jpg -thumbnail 300x200 -bordercolor white -border 10 \
       -bordercolor grey60 -border 1 -bordercolor none \
       -background none -rotate 6 \
    \) \
    \
    \( img-3.jpg -thumbnail 300x200 -bordercolor white -border 10 \
       -bordercolor grey60 -border 1 -bordercolor none \
       -background none -rotate -2 \
    \) \
    \
    \( img-1.jpg -thumbnail 300x200 -bordercolor white -border 10 \
       -bordercolor grey60 -border 1 -bordercolor none \
       -background none -rotate -4 \
    \) \
    \
    \( img-4.jpg -thumbnail 300x200 -bordercolor white -border 10 \
       -bordercolor grey60 -border 1 -bordercolor none \
       -background none -rotate 4 \
    \) \
    \
    -border 100x80 -gravity center +repage -flatten -trim +repage \
    -background black \( +clone -shadow 60x4+4+4 \) +swap -background none \
    -flatten stack.png
```

This command generated the following image:

[image: Polaroid Stack]

What I'd like to be able to do is offset the images away from the center pivot currently used by the rotate option so that there is more horizontal (and perhaps a little vertical) separation between the photos.

More specifically, I'd like to be able to see just a little more of the underlying images showing around the edges of the top-most image by shifting them to the left and right (and perhaps a little up and down).

What commands can I add to my convert call above to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Iamiuru for putting me on the right track. Unfortunately, -repage on its own wasn't enough, I had to make some adjustments elsewhere to make it work.

Here is the command I ended up using:

```
convert \
    img-5.jpg -thumbnail 300x200 -bordercolor white -border 10 \
    -bordercolor grey60 -border 1 -bordercolor none \
    -background none -rotate 3 -repage -20-5 \
    \
    \( img-2.jpg -thumbnail 300x200 -bordercolor white -border 10 \
       -bordercolor grey60 -border 1 -bordercolor none \
       -background none -rotate -5 -repage -10+0 \
    \) \
    \
    \( img-3.jpg -thumbnail 300x200 -bordercolor white -border 10 \
       -bordercolor grey60 -border 1 -bordercolor none \
       -background none -rotate 4 -repage -30+10 \
    \) \
    \
    \( img-1.jpg -thumbnail 300x200 -bordercolor white -border 10 \
       -bordercolor grey60 -border 1 -bordercolor none \
       -background none -rotate -4 -repage +20-10 \
    \) \
    \
    \( img-4.jpg -thumbnail 300x200 -bordercolor white -border 10 \
       -bordercolor grey60 -border 1 -bordercolor none \
       -background none -rotate 2 \
    \) \
    \
    -border 100x80 -flatten -trim +repage -background black \
    \( +clone -shadow 60x4+4+4 \) +swap -background none -flatten stack.png
```

From my original command, I had to remove the `-gravity center +repage` options, since these simply re-centered all of the images back to their original locations and the -repage would not work.

This command generated the following image:

[image: Polaroid stack with offset]

Answer (score 1):

```
-repage geometry

Adjust the canvas and offset information of the image.
```

Here is a good example from imagemagick.org http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#layer_prog

Comment: Thanks - that was what I needed. I found I had to make some other adjustments to my original command to make it work though.